# Mass Updates to SQL Server 2008 database using .Net Application - most performant method

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

We have an application which posts large numbers of changes to a table (table 1) in a SQL Server 2000 Database.

Each Insert/Update/Delete fires a trigger on that table, and posts the details of the change into another table (table 2), including the unique key of table 1.

Then at specific intervals a .Net application polls table 2, to see if there are any updates that need to be transferred to an identical table to table 1 in a SQL Server 2008 database - table 3.
The routine takes the "top 10000" rows of changes and applies them individualy to table 3, repeating the process until there are none left. Each 10,000 takes about a minute to process, including the mass update of table 2 to indicate the transfer of data completed.

Each update to table 3 is performed using the unique key, and the indexing on the table is sound.

Once the update is complete to table 3, table 2 is updated to show the transaction has been applied to the SQL Server 2008 database.

Table 1 is sometimes hit with 40,000 updates, these seem to work fine, but the SQl Server 2008 database suffers when the records are updated there.

What's the most performant way to post the updates to table 3?

I though service broker may do the job, but how do I create the XML message in the .Net app and have it placed on the queue for service broker to apply - and wouldn't it cause the same problems anyway - same job carried out by a different process.

Comment: Have you looked into replication or even do it in a SQL job?

Comment: Paul, I wanted to complete this job with T-SQL only when it first came up. Because I was using both SQL 2000 and SQL 2008 Databases I found there was nothing that would do the job acceptably. I did think about openquery but that didn't seem to do the job either. If you have a suggestion that you know will work - I am all ears!

Comment: You've most likely tried everything I could suggest but sometimes a sql answer isn't always obvious to developers.  If possible I would have tried to link the servers and do all the heavy work in the SQL 2008 server but again, I'm probably over-simplifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Using service broker will not magically make your workload faster. Why do you expect that?

The most efficient way to do bulk DML is usually to execute it in bigger batches per query. This allows the optimizer to tune the query plan for the exact amount of rows it will receive. If you execute each update as a single query the optimizer cannot optimize across queries.

So I recommend you try to fit all updates into a single merge statement. Also include the inserts and deletes in this single merge query.

Comment: usr - Sorry if I wasn't clear, I didn't expect service broker to magically fix the problem, hence my comment "...service broker to apply - and wouldn't it cause the same problems anyway - same job carried out by a different process." I do like your comment about a single merge query though. But "single merge query" is a new phrase to me. Do you mean a merge statement (I've never used one before) or something else?

Comment: Yes, a merge statement. It can have up to three DML sub-clauses. In your case one for insert, one for update and one for deletes.